# How do I properly use generate statements in VHDL? <- Multiple generates that is

Tags: vhdl, fft

I'm trying to properly generate a loop across 32 different possibilities. It's a structural VHDL code, so I'm using generate statements to create the entities. Of the 32 possibilities, I'm only going to be using 16 of those 32 possibilities in the code, and of those 16 possibilities, each set of 4 will be the same construction of the entity.

In other words, I want to construct an entity for possibilities 0 through 3, 8 through 11, 16 to 19, and 24 to 27 of the total 32 loop.

Currently, I've tried using generate statements that just work in the established range.

```
     g1: for i in 0 to 3 generate

    a1 : entity work.single_dft(structural) 
           .... 
     end generate g1; 

     g2: for i in 8 to 11 generate
           .... 
     end generate g2; 

     g3: for i in 16 to 19 generate
           ....
     end generate g3; 

     g4: for i in 24 to 27 generate
           ....
     end generate g4;
```

I'm expecting to be able to refer to "i" as a digit between 0 to 3 from g1, "i" as digit between 8 to 11 from g2, "i" as digit between 16 to 19 from g3, and "i" as digit between 24 to 27 from g4.

EDIT: As a little bit of a backstory, this is the approach I'm using in my goal to construct my own 32 bit FFT using the Radix 2 DIF algorithm. Essentially, the entity that I'm calling with each generate loop is an entity that performs the cross (add, sub, multiply), provided the correct inputs.

Comment: why not use a single generate look and us if..generate to for conditional instantiation?

Comment: Without more information or a specific problem and a [mcve] your readers can't tell if your approach is viable. The determination revolves around scope and visibility of declarations which you don't show. The 4 generate statements will elaborate into 16 block statements each with a constant i declared with the generate schemes i value for a particular iteration. Which blocks communicate with which other blocks and where are those signals declared? It's not apparent from your question. What's proper?